# Hex ANDing in Excel and/or Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel, hex

I'm trying to `AND` two hex number bit-wise in `Excel/Visual Basic`.

Ex. `53FDBC AND 00FFFF` which should yield `00FDBC`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have your 2 values stored as strings.  In this case you could do the following:

```
Dim hex1 As String
hex1 = "53FDBC"

Dim hex2 As String
hex2 = "00FFFF"

Dim bin1 As String
bin1 = CLng("&H" & hex1)

Dim bin2 As String
bin2 = CLng("&H" & hex2)

Dim result As String
result = Hex$(bin1 And bin2)
```

*result* now contains "FDBC", but you may wish to pad this to the left with zeroes

As a function (excel module) this could be implemented as:

```
Function hexand(hex1 As String, hex2 As String) as String

Dim bin1 As String
bin1 = CLng("&H" & hex1)

Dim bin2 As String
bin2 = CLng("&H" & hex2)

hexand = Hex$(bin1 And bin2)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

iirc, it's built-in, only bit shifting operators are not built-in

&H53FDBC And &H00FFFF

Answer (score 0):

hex value of 0xFFFF in Decimal is 65536
hex value of 0x53FDBC in Decimal is 5504444

So you can use =DEC2HEX(MOD(5504444,65536))